# Rasising positive integrs to $c,\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$ rarely gives an integer!

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:**  Let $c>0$ be a real number, and suppose that for every positive integer $n$, at least one percent of the numbers $1^c,2^c,3^c,\ldots,n^c$ are integers. Prove that $c$ is an integer.

**My progress:** At first we will deal with the case when $c$ is a rational number. Suppose  $c=\frac{a}{b}$. It indeed suffices to prove the statement for rationals of the form $\frac{1}{a}$. Observe that there are $\lfloor{M^{\frac{1}{a}}}\rfloor$ integers of the form $n^{\frac{1}{a}}$ between $1$ and $M$. So the percentage of integers of the form $n^{\frac{1}{a}}$ among the first $M$ integers is
$$\frac{\lfloor{M^{\frac{1}{a}}}\rfloor}{M}\times 100\le \frac{M^{\frac{1}{a}}}{M}\times 100=\frac{100}{M^{1-\frac{1}{a}}}$$
which will be less than 1 for sufficiently large $M$.

But I am unable to prove the problem for any real $c$. I tried approximating reals with a sequence of rational numbers, but it didn't work well.

Comment: This question needs recognition.

Comment: Do post this on Mathoverflow (but phrase it as a research problem, otherwise those who have allergy towards olympiad problems will vote for closing it).

Comment: It has now been posted on MathOverflow at [Raising positive integer to $c,\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$ rarely gives an integer!](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332532/raising-positive-integer-to-c-in-mathbbr-mathbbn-rarely-gives-an-integer).

Comment: @Kawa Behold an Israelite indeed, in whom is no guile!